# Adding a new line of data on a sheet based on drop down information

Tags: excel, vba

I have a question of "is it possible" more than "how exactly do I do this". I am contemplating shelling out cash for accounting software, but as I look at them I keep thinking "I bet excel could do all of this". I am a semi-experienced computer programmer (I went to school for CS and have VB experience but never used it professionally) so I am not afraid of code. Here is what I am wondering is possible.

I have one sheet that tally's the total number of donations given on a particular day, along with each line includes a name of the person donating, and the amount donated. Then each individual person each also has their own sheet detailing all of their donations for a year. Is it possible that when I enter the first set of data (A line with a name and then a donation amount) that excel could read the name, and then based on that name update that persons own unique sheet of total donations? If so, can you suggest a term or phrase to Google that I may not know so I can look it up? Thanks!

Comment: It sure is possible.  Look at Worksheet_Change, and you'll need to find the sheet by sheet name, etc..  Get some code started and post it back here when/if you hit a wall.

Comment: You are a rockstar Matthew, that is exactly the kind of answer I was looking for. I will certainly do that!

Comment: @pnuts, thanks! I have some experience with Google sheets, even more than Excel, but I need a fully robust offline experience for this one.